# windows CMD send CRLF inside double quote

Tags: cmd, ffmpeg, newline

I want to pass multiple headers for ffplay or ffmpeg, it say I need to split with CRLF. on linux I can use `\` or `$'\r\n'` but how for windows?

```
SET CRLF=^
ffplay -v debug -i "http://example.com/test" -headers "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5%CRLF%Connection: keep-alive"
```

debug log: `Connection: keep-alive` is not sent

```
[http @ 04df3f40] No trailing CRLF found in HTTP header.
[http @ 04df3f40] request: GET /test HTTP/1.1 0KB sq=    0B f=0/0
User-Agent: Lavf/57.37.101
Accept: */*
Range: bytes=0-
Connection: close
Host: example.com
Icy-MetaData: 1
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please try to set CRLF in this way. It might work.

```
C:\Users\pwatson>type t.bat
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM === The following line -MUST- be followed by two (2) blank lines.
SET CRLF=^


REM === DO NOT EDIT THE PREVIOUS TWO (2) LINES

echo this is a!CRLF!new line
```

Then, run it.

```
C:\Users\pwatson>call t.bat
this is a
new line
```

Answer (score 0):

After using @[lit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/447901/lit)'s answer (of setting a new CRLF environment variable, adding two blank lines after it, and then using !CRLF! instead of real line breaks), you need to run your batch file with enabled "delayed environment variable expansion" in order for the exclamation mark to work (instead of the percentage mark):

cmd /v:on /c mybatfile.bat

Or inside the original batch file add the following line:

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion